# How do I pass the text data from firestore inside the expandable row and get the document ID to be passed inside the setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, mui-datatable

In firestore, I have this fields `title`, `createdDate`, and `text`. How do I display the fields `title` and `createdDate` in the mui-datatable. The `text` would then be displayed inside the expanded row. How can I do this?

This is what the data looks like if I'll console.log the `blogs`:
[image]

```
const columns = ["Title", "Created Date"];
const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
const unsubscribe = firestore
  .collection("blogs")
  .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    const arr = [];
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const data = doc.data();
      arr.push({
        text: parse(data.text),
        Title: data.title,
        "Created Date": new Date(
          data.createdDate.seconds * 1000
        ).toDateString(),
      });
    });
    setBlogs(arr);
    setIsLoading(true);
  });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  const options = {
    filter: true,
    expandableRows: true,
    renderExpandableRow: (rowData, rowMeta) => {
      console.log(); //how do I render the `text` here from firestore?
    },

  };
```

Inside the return: I tried putting the `blogs` inside the data but it doesn't work. No data is showing.

```
 <MUIDataTable
    title={"List"}
    columns={columns}
    data={blogs}
    options={options}
  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move your `setBlogs` inside the `onSnapshot` listener like here:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = firestore
    .collection("blogs")
    .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      const arr = [];
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const data = doc.data();
        arr.push({
          text: parse(data.text),
          Title: data.title,
          "Created Date": new Date(data.createdDate.seconds * 1000).toDateString(),
        });
        setBlogs(arr);
      });
    
      setIsLoading(true);
  });

  return () => {
    unsubscribe();
  };
}, []);
```

If it's outside of the `onSnapshot` listener you would always set the `blogs` as empty array because the `setBlogs` would be executed before the `onSnapshot` listener is fired.

This is they way you can redner and expandable row:

```js
import MUIDataTable, {ExpandButton} from "../../src/";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";

 const options = {
      filter: true,
      filterType: 'dropdown',
      responsive: 'standard',
      expandableRows: true,
      expandableRowsHeader: false,
      expandableRowsOnClick: true,
      isRowExpandable: (dataIndex, expandedRows) => {
        if (dataIndex === 3 || dataIndex === 4) return false;

        // Prevent expand/collapse of any row if there are 4 rows expanded already (but allow those already expanded to be collapsed)
        if (expandedRows.data.length > 4 && expandedRows.data.filter(d => d.dataIndex === dataIndex).length === 0) return false;
        return true;
      },
      rowsExpanded: [0, 1],
      renderExpandableRow: (rowData, rowMeta) => {
        const colSpan = rowData.length + 1;
        return (
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell colSpan={colSpan}>
              Custom expandable row option. Data: {JSON.stringify(rowData)}
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        );
      },
      onRowExpansionChange: (curExpanded, allExpanded, rowsExpanded) => console.log(curExpanded, allExpanded, rowsExpanded)
    };
```

It's from the example [here](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables/blob/master/examples/expandable-rows/index.js#L84). Just make sure if your data structure can work with the example (maybe you would need to adopt it a little bit).

Comment: oh alright, thank you. But how can I put the field `text` inside the `renderExpandableRow`?

Comment: I have added some example code in the answer.